# SAS: creating benchmark period dummies (around event)

Tags: events, sas, benchmarking

I want to do an event study and need some descriptives around the events I am testing with different window sizes.

Let's assume I have a data set with 10000 observations (stocks, dates, measures) and merge them with an announcement data set. Now, I want to get a dummy variable that is always 0 except for parameters given by me:

if date = announcement_date then;

window_dummy at t-60 to t-11 = 1
or
window_dummy at t-5 to t+5 = 1

I hope I described it appropriately and there is a way because there is no lead function or similar.

Best
M

Comment: Please add sample data and what code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather from this, you wish to have additional variable, which creates window (or binning) variable reaching x days to past and future;

First we generate some test data. SAS dates are just numbers so:

```
data begin; 
    do i = 21040 to 21080;
        my_date= i;
        output;
    end;
    drop i;
run;
```

Next we calculate the window:

```
%let act_date= 21060;

%let min_date= %eval(&act_date - 5); /*5 days to past*/
%let max_date= %eval(&act_date + 3); /*3 days to future*/
```

Then it's left to generate the dummy variable:

```
data refined; 
    set begin;
    if  &min_date <= my_date and 
        my_date <= &max_date then 
            dummy = 1;
    else dummy = 0;
run;
```

Now, one can calculate this all in single datastep, but maybe this is more informative way.

Edit: you can specify windows as you please. In your case you could have:

```
min_date1= %eval(&act_date - 60);
max_date2= %eval(&act_date - 11); 
....
```

Then just add them to the if clause with **or** operator.